# Prove that $\frac12 + \cos (a) + \cos (2a) + ... + \cos (na) = \frac{\sin ((n+1/2)a)}{ 2sin(a/2)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, complex-numbers, trigonometric-series

I need to prove that :

> $$ \frac{1}{2} + \cos (\theta ) + \cos(2\theta ) + ... + \cos(n \theta) = \frac{\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})\theta))}{2\sin(\frac{\theta}{2}))}  \;\;\;\;\;\; (1)$$

What I did :

- I have evaluated this series using Euler's formulas :

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{ik\theta} 
=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(e^{ik\theta}) - 1 
=e^{i\theta} \frac{1 - e^{i(n+1))\theta } }{1 - e^{i\theta}} - 1
=e^{i\theta} \cdot e^{i\frac{n\theta}{2}} \frac{\sin(\frac{n+1}{2}\theta)}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2}))} -1
=e^{i(\theta+\frac{n\theta}{2})}  \frac{\sin(\frac{n+1}{2}\theta)}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2}))} - 1$

- Now, knowing that $\cos(x)=\Re(e^{ix})$ we get :

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos(kx) = \Re(\sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{ik\theta} ) =  \cos(\theta + \frac{n\theta}{2})\frac{\sin(\frac{n+1}{2}\theta)}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2}))} - 1 $

- Re-plugging into (1) we have the following equation :

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} + \cos(\theta + \frac{n\theta}{2})\frac{\sin(\frac{n+1}{2}\theta)}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2}))} - 1 = -\frac{1}{2} + \cos(\theta + \frac{n\theta}{2})\frac{\sin(\frac{n+1}{2}\theta)}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2}))} $

Am I doing something wrong ? Because I have the feeling that the argument in cos is not right. If the argument are the same in cos and sin I can use some trigonometric identities and finish the proof.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The proof would be simpler if you use induction.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{ik\theta} 
=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(e^{ik\theta}) - 1 
=\frac{1 - e^{i(n+1))\theta } }{1 - e^{i\theta}} - 1
=e^{i\frac{n\theta}{2}} \frac{\sin(\frac{n+1}{2}\theta)}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2}))} -1$

Comment: There is an extra factor $e^{i\theta}$ appearing early.

Comment: Where exactly please ?

Comment: see my comment above please. While summing it from k=0 to $n$.

Comment: Oh ok I see. But without $e^{i\theta}$ we get cos(n*theta/2) at the end. Args are still different and don't know what to do.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["How can we sum up sin and cos
 series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/409). In particular, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1214626/409) uses Euler's formula.

Comment: @user474986: I am not so sure, compare the given answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Probably the fastest way:**

$$2S=\sum_{k=\color{red}{-n}}^n e^{ika}=\frac{e^{i(n+1)a}-e^{-ina}}{e^{ia}-1}=\frac{e^{i(n+1/2)a}-e^{-i(n+1/2)a}}{e^{ia/2}-e^{-ia/2}}=\frac{\sin(n+\frac12)a}{\sin\frac12a}.$$

Answer (score 1):

By mathematical induction on $n$

For $n=0$ the equation reduces to $1/2=1/2$.  Now suppose it holds for $n=k$ and add $\cos((k+1)a)$:

$(1/2)+\cos(a)+\cos(2a)+...+\cos((k+1)a)=\dfrac{\sin((k+(1/2)a)}{2\sin(a/2)}+\cos((k+1)a)$

Then

$\dfrac{\sin((k+(1/2)a)}{2\sin(a/2)}+\cos((k+1)a)=\dfrac{\sin((k+(1/2))a)+2\sin(a/2)cos((k+1)a)}{2\sin(a/2)}$

And with $\cos(u)\sin(v)=(1/2)(\sin(u+v)-\sin(u-v))$:

$2\sin(a/2)\cos((k+1)a)=\sin(((k+1)+(1/2))a)-\sin((k+(1/2))a)$

Substituting this into the last term of the numerator then proves the claim for $n=k+1$:

$(1/2)+\cos(a)+\cos(2a)+...+\cos((k+1)a)=\dfrac{\sin(((k+1)+(1/2))a)}{2\sin(a/2)}$.

Comment: Very helpful thanks !

Comment: When you try so hard with induction, then someone uses complex number and destroys it... good effort though :))

Comment: Haha yeah the induction works but I spend a while with a solution using complex numbers....  :))

Comment: @Gareth I wanted to see how induction would work on this problem.