# A series in cosine : $\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j-1}\cos\left(\frac{j\pi}{2n+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

$\textbf{Question :}$ Prove that $$\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j-1}\cos\left(\frac{j\pi}{2n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

$\textbf{My Attempt :}$

Let $n$ be odd (will do even case later) then the series can be written as

$$S = \sum_{j=1}^{(n+1)/2}\cos((2j-1)x) - \sum_{j=1}^{(n-1)/2} \cos(2jx)$$

where $x = \frac{\pi}{2n+1}$

Now as both the cosine series are just arithmetic progressions in their angles with the common difference of $2x$, we can simplify $S$ as follows :

$$S = \frac{1}{\sin x}(\sin((n+3)x)\cos((n+2)x)-\sin((n+1)x)\cos(nx))$$

As $2\sin a\cos b = \sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)$

$$S = \frac{1}{2\sin x}(\sin(2n+5)x)-\sin((2n+1)x)$$

Again as $\sin c -\sin d = 2\sin((c+d)/2)\cos((c-d)/2)$

$$S = \frac{1}{2 \sin x} (2\sin 2x \cos((2n+3)x))$$

$$S = \cos x \cos ((2n+3)x)$$
Now this is where I am getting stuck, I can't get it equal to any constant...

Comment: You can use  $\cos x={\rm Re}\,e^{ix}.$ Then you will sum a geometric sequence.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I tried that but then how to solve this : $$\Re\left( \frac{e^{ix}}{e^{ix}+1}(1-(-1)^ne^{inx})\right)$$

Comment: More problematically, I cannot understand how you can conclude that a function of an arithmetic sequence can be evaluated in the way that you propose.  You are missing several steps in between that you have not used to justify your calculation.

Comment: @heropup you can prove this quite easily, here is the result : $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \cos(a+jd)=\frac{\sin(nd/2)}{\sin(d/2)}\cos\left(a+\frac{(n-1)d}{2}\right)$$

Comment: And I think I may have applied the cosine arithmetic progression series formula in a wrong way

Comment: My first try, which might fail, would be to convert all the even numbered terms from negative to positive, through the use of the identify $~\cos(\pi - \alpha) = - \cos(\alpha). ~$  Then, I would attempt to use the $~T = R - S~$ approach, from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4672579/prove-a-relation-based-on-angles-frac-pi11-and-frac-pi22/4672723#4672723).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\cos \frac{x}{2} \cdot \sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j-1}\cos(j x)\\
 ={}& \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j-1}
 \frac12[\cos(j x - x/2) + \cos(jx + x/2)]\\
 ={}& \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j-1}
 \frac12\cos(j x - x/2) + \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j-1} \frac12\cos(jx + x/2)\\
 ={}&\frac12 \cos \frac{x}{2}
 + \sum_{j=2}^n (-1)^{j-1}
 \frac12\cos(j x - x/2) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{j-1} \frac12\cos(jx + x/2) \\
&\qquad + (-1)^{n-1}\frac12\cos(nx + x/2)\\
 ={}&\frac12 \cos \frac{x}{2}
 - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{j-1}
 \frac12\cos(j x + x/2) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{j-1} \frac12\cos(jx + x/2)\\
&\qquad + (-1)^{n-1}\frac12\cos(nx + x/2)\\
 ={}& \frac12 \cos \frac{x}{2} + (-1)^{n-1}\frac12\cos(nx + x/2)
\end{align*}
which results in (when $\cos (x/2) \ne 0$)
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j-1}\cos(j x) = \frac12 + \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos(nx + x/2)}{2\cos (x/2)}.$$

Letting $x = \frac{\pi}{2n + 1}$, the desired result follows.

Answer (score 3):

Using $-\cos(x) = \cos(\pi -x)$ we can write
$$
S =\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j-1}\cos\left(\frac{j\pi}{2n+1}\right)
$$
in the form $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos (a+k \cdot d)$, which is a well-known expression.

Let $N$ be the largest odd integer $\le n$, then $2n-1-N$ is the largest even integer $\le n$. The terms for odd $j$ in $S$ are
$$
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+1}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2n+1}\right)+ \cdots + \cos\left(\frac{N\pi}{2n+1}\right)
$$
and the terms for even $j$ in $S$ are
$$
-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{2n+1}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{2n+1}\right)- \cdots - \cos\left(\frac{(2n-1-N)\pi}{2n+1}\right)\\
= \cos\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2n+1}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{(2n-3)\pi}{2n+1}\right)+ \cdots + \cos\left(\frac{(N+2)\pi}{2n+1}\right) \, .
$$
Therefore, regardless whether $n$ is even or odd, the given sum is equal to
$$
S = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n+1}\right) \, .
$$
That sum can be evaluated with well-known techniques, see for example [How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/42969):
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos (a+k \cdot d) =\frac{\sin(n \times \frac{d}{2})}{\sin ( \frac{d}{2} )} \times \cos \biggl( \frac{ 2 a + (n-1)\cdot d}{2}\biggr) \, .
$$

Here we have $a = \pi/(2n+1)$ and $d = 2\pi/(2n+1)$, so that
$$
 S = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{n}{2n+1}\pi\right)\cos \left(\frac{n}{2n+1}\pi\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\pi\right)}  =
\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\pi\right)}{2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\pi\right)} = \frac 12 \, .
$$